# Python PVLib Combine IV-curves in parallel

Tags: python, pvlib

I am using PVLib to model pv power loss due to the mismatch effect.

Is it possible to add module IV-curves, which are connected in parallel?

Similar to:

```
def combine_series(dfs):
    """
    Combine IV curves in series by aligning currents and summing voltages.
    The current range is based on the first curve's current range.
    """
    df1 = dfs[0]
    imin = df1['i'].min()
    imax = df1['i'].max()
    i = np.linspace(imin, imax, 1000)
    v = 0
    for df2 in dfs:
        v_cell = interpolate(df2, i)
        v += v_cell
    return pd.DataFrame({'i': i, 'v': v})
```

with the difference that it should be combined in parallel.

thank you so much,
Kilian

Answer (score 1):

Think I got it:

```
def interpolate_p(df, v):
"""convenience wrapper around scipy.interpolate.interp1d"""
f_interp = interp1d(df['v'], df['i'], kind='linear',
                    fill_value='extrapolate')
return f_interp(v)

def combine_parallel(dfs):
"""
Combine IV curves in parallel by aligning voltages and summing currents.
The current range is based on the first curve's voltage range.
"""
df1 = dfs[0]
imin = df1['v'].min()
imax = df1['v'].max()
v = np.linspace(imin, imax, 1000)
i = 0
for df2 in dfs:
    v_cell = interpolate_p(df2, v)
    i += v_cell
return pd.DataFrame({'i': i, 'v': v})
```

That worked out I guess. Feel free to use and tell me if I am wrong or if there is another function inside PVLib.

Regards
Kilian

Comment: Glad to see you gave it a shot yourself.  I would rename some more of those variables though.  It looks a bit odd to add voltage and current...